# Proving if monotonic or strictly monotonic

Tags: calculus

I have a function and its derivative in the given interval is always greater than or equal to 0, f'(x)>=0. I am asked to speak about the monotonicity of this function. I know it is monotonic and increasing in the interval from its graph and also the derivative however, how do i know if it is strictly monotonic or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the derivative $f'(x)\geq 0$, there is a point $t$ where $f'(t)=0$, at which point $f(x)$ will be flat, not increasing.  Hence, the function is just monotonically increasing; it would be *strictly* increasing if $f'(x)>0$.

In this sense, "increasing" really means "non-decreasing".